# Need to install pip for python 3

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.3

I have installed python 2.7 and python 3.3 on server and now my need is to install pip for python 3.

Here what I have tried so far.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

This will install pip for python 3.2 ( I don't have installed python 3.2),

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

This will install pip for python 3.2

> **My need is to install few packages with python3.3 (lxml, ftplib, etc...) for**
>   **that I need pip but unfortunately I was unable to do this.**

I can not setup only python 3.3 because basic need is python 2.7 (for odoo).

Can anyone guide me in proper direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

you should be able to install packages with pip3 command. 
Try:

```
pip --version
pip3 --version
```